# remove Js alert in home page

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery, javascript

I dont know whats the probleme , to be honest i have no idea how joomla works

i have a joomla website and every time i visit the homepage a JS alert shows up

[image]

i really could not find the solution , does any one knows how to?

**Update**

when i use inscpect element ( in chrome) i found this
[image]

i dont know how joomla works behind the scenes so how i can find the file which has this code?

Comment: Have you installed a custom template or extension since you installed Joomla? If so, have you checked the options for this template/extension to see if there's anything related to an alert message?

Comment: of course i have installed a theme (templates+extensions) i have a 'ja_charity - Home' template, only when i use this one the probleme occurs

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer of the template?

Comment: no, i think if i can fix it if i downloadall files , put them in sublime , search for the 'we ready rock your world' , remove the js block and save right?

Comment: Yup, you can do that, but it would also be best to notify the developer as others have have the same issue as you and may not know how to do it. An official template update would be beneficial ;)

Comment: i think it can be disabled since its only in home page(only when using the home template)

Answer (score 1):

Just click on view HTML and see, in the code, where that popup is being displayed. If you found it but the code is somehow obfuscated, then most likely your website is hacked.

If you can't find it, then do a grep (if you have access to a VPS) at the root level of your Joomla website:

```
grep -R "We Ready"
```

If the grep didn't return any results, then try searching the database (the whole database) in phpMyAdmin.

If you still can't find it, then try overwriting your core JavaScript files with clean JavaScript files from Joomla's website.

If that still didn't work for you, then try switching to a different template to see if the problem persists. If the problem is gone, then it's the template, and the code is obfuscated there.

Comment: that you, i update the question ,check edit,